# Kernel configuation for android does not work

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I want to compile Linux kernel for Android.

I have a kernel configuration

```
CONFIG_SDCARD_FS=y
```

in the file `device/qcom/msmxxxx/msm_defconfig`.

The module is located in the directory `kernel/fs/sdcardfs`.

I have code

```
source "fs/sdcardfs/Kconfig"
```

in the file `kernel/fs/Kconfig`

and code

```
obj-$(CONFIG_SDCARD_FS)     += sdcardfs/
```

in the file `kernel/fs/Makefile`.

But I find that the module corresponding to this configuration is not compiled.

Comment: You may verify configuration value by inspecting `.config` file, no needs in attempting to build. You say that you **modify** file `device/qcom/msmxxxx/msm_defconfig`, but don't show how do you **use** that file in configuration process. Did you perform `make defconfig` or similar?

Comment: How did you check that? You choose built-in instead of module, btw.

Comment: I find out the reason. I should modify the file `device/qcom/msmxxxx/msmcore_defconfig` rather than `device/qcom/msmxxxx/msm_defconfig`.